# Save tuple or list or 1-D array features with variable length in TFRecord

Tags: tensorflow

I want to save my dataset in TFRecord. I have no problem with saving `float` type features something like this:

```
feature={}
feature.update({feat_name: tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=[feat_value]))})

example_proto = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))
example_proto.SerializeToString()
```

How to save the features that have tuple/list/1-D array type with variable length (meaning each example might have different list length)?

The real use case of this is to save predecessor or successor IDs of each node in a graph. One example is one node, each node has its numerical node features (which can be easily saved as float type as above), but I also want to save the predecessor and successor IDs of each node to later construct the graph in the downstream process. The number of predecessors/successors might vary (a node can have none or multiple predecessors) hence they will be saved as either tuple or list or 1-D array with variable length.

How to save that in TFRecord on Tensorflow 2?

Thanks a lot

Comment: `tf.data.Dataset` supported types: Elements can be nested structures of tuples, named tuples, and dictionaries. More information visit [Tensorflow link](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#supported_types_2)